# bl_idname requirements for 2.80

Tags: python

The [python api change notes for 2.80](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API/Addons) give new requirements for bl_idname. I'm getting an error telling me that "MAPLUS_OT_changetypebaseclass" is an invalid name:

```
RuntimeError: Error: Registering operator class: 'ChangeTypeBaseClass', invalid bl_idname 'MAPLUS_OT_changetypebaseclass', at position 0
```

Am I following the naming requirements properly? The [addon file is here](https://github.com/egtwobits/mesh_align_plus/blob/f898be7668038a1e98fde1ea63f8f33f3553e3c1/mesh_mesh_align_plus.py) for reference.

Answer (score 3):

Expected a class name including `_OT_`
This should work.

```
class MAPLUS_OT_changetypebaseclass(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "maplus.changetypebaseclass"
```

Comment: TO elaborate for OP: this has not changed: For operator to be known as  `bpy.ops.foo.bar()` requires `bl_idname = "foo.bar"` (Lower case one dot, _this is the error you are seeing "M"  at position 0 is not lower case (and nextly there's no dot))_  Blender will generate a  registered class   `bpy.types.FOO_OT_bar`For other registerable types the `bl_idname` (if omitted is the class name)  and needs to follow the naming convention to avoid the warning message

Comment: The wiki page specifically notes: "Valid Examples: OBJECT_OT_fancy_tool", and notes that "This constraint applies to the bl_idname of each class (or the class name which uses it if no bl_idname is defined in the class)". So, is the addons page wrong, or is this just a case of these features not being implemented? It seems very unclear to me based on the language on the wiki...I just want to clearly understand the full requirements for bl_idname and/or class name(s).

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind 2.8 is very Beta. But I could be wrong, but I'm surprised thats the only error you're getting. I thought all of the class names were to be changed? But I saw that on this programmers video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mjy-zGG3Wk4

So I don't know if this generates errors or not.